# Why does i+1 do increment while i++ does not

Tags: java

Lets say I got this piece of code:

```
public class Incrementor {

    private int i;

    public int getInt(){
        return i;
    }

    private void incrementA(){
        i = i+1;
    }

    private void incrementB(){
        i = i++;
    }
}
```

- When I call `incrementA()` before calling `getInt()` the value will be 1.
- When I call `incrementB()` before calling `getInt()` the value will be 0.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment

```
i = i++;
```

is basically equivalent to

```
// These two lines corresponds to i++
int temporary_variable = i;
i = i + 1;

// This line is your assignment back to i
i = temporary_variable;
```

The postfix `++` operator returns the *old* value, before incrementing.

If all you want to do is increment the variable, no assignment is needed as it's built into the `++` operation itself:

```
private void incrementB(){
    i++;  // Increment i by one
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`i++` returns the value of `i` before the increment happened. The code `i = i++` is equal to `i = i`.

Answer (score 3):

```
    i = i++;
```

While this syntax is perfectly valid, it isn't doing what you think. It should just be:

```
    i++;
```

`i++` is a post-increment operator, meaning it returns the value of i prior to being incremented when used as the right hand side of an expression.

Comment: "The syntax here is wrong" The syntax is fine. It's just that it doesn't do anything that you would ever need.

Comment: True - I meant his syntax was wrong for what he wanted to achieve. You're correct, it's perfectly valid.